# Is there a way to perform integer division in the iOS Shortcuts app?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

The *Calculate* shortcut-let provides floating point operations & *Modulus* is available as an option. I guess I can cobble something together with rounding (provided in *Round Number*) but was hoping there was a native *div* hiding somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any other way than your suggestion with the module round numbers. I personally think it's a good compromise, because you only need one additional module to the calculation module for your routine.

In the routine you define the method to always round down with 0 decimal places.